# Set collectionView size. (sizeForItemAtIndexPath function is not working) Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I have a `tableView` and in every `tableViewCell` is a `collectionView`.

I am trying to change the collectionView size with this code:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if collectionView.tag == 2{

        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    }else if collectionView.tag == 4 {


        return CGSize(width: 222, height: 200)

    }else{


        return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
    }

}
```

The problem is that there is no error but cells do not change sizes

If you need to know something more, just write a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first statement says you have a `tableView`, but this looks like a `collectionView`. Do you have both, or just one?

Comment: @brandonscript  there is a collection view inside table view cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So This is my code right now and it works:

```
        collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        collectionView.tag = row
        collectionView.setContentOffset(collectionView.contentOffset, animated:false)
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "eventsCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "eventsCollectionViewCell")


        if row == 2{


            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

            collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

        }else if row == 4 {


            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 222, height: 200)
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

            collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

        }else{

            print("else")
        }
```

Comment: What is row? How and where its declared and assigned?

Answer (score 301):

First, don't forget extends from **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** delegate.

For single collectionview display logic :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = ((collectionView.frame.width - 15) / 2) // 15 because of paddings
    print("cell width : \(width)")
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 200)
}
```

**And important point in storyboard don't forget Estimate Size : None**

[image: estimate_size_none]

Comment: Wow. You saved my day. After changing the Estimate Size from Automatic to None(+ Min Spacing For Cells from 10 to 0 and For Lines from 10 to 0),  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) worked! Before the edit I was experiencing unexpected cell width and min spacing for cells.

Comment: Yes @mazend and I faced same problem. After a long time, I discovered by chance. I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: I am using XCode 11.2.1 and this version has "Automatic" value as default for Estimate Size. So change it to None worked for me. Thanks man!

Comment: Weird XCode additions... right answer for XCode 11.2.1, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the estimated size point... wasted literally half a day on it debugging my size for item

Comment: This is also needed if you use `xib`'s as well for your `collectionView`

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is the tricky part for me.

Comment: Yes, it's working. After changing the Estimate Size from Automatic to None.

Answer (score 63):

The signature for this method has changed in Swift 3 to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // your code here
}
```

Pay attention to the subtle difference: `(_ collectionView: ...` instead of `(collectionView: ...`.

This is because in Swift 3, you have to explicitly specify the label of the first parameter. You can override this default behaviour by adding the underscore character `_`.

Also, make sure that your class adopts both `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocols

```
class MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    // your code here

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Refer to [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/swift3-changes/) to learn more about changes in Swift 3.

Comment: I have updated my code but it does not change the cell size :/

Comment: add "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout" in delgate call

Comment: This is the right answer. Thank you so much for this! UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is key

Comment: @BaljeetSingh what do you mean by "add "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout" in delgate call"?

Comment: @nambatee    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -1, left: -1, bottom: -1, right: -1)
        let value:CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width)/2;
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: value, height: value)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        GridView!.collectionViewLayout = layout

Comment: for me it was UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, previous developer didn't add that.

Answer (score 23):

You need to specify that you implement the protocol UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your class declaration.

```
class PhrasesCompactCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
```

Answer (score 3):

**Short Version**:

Try adding

```
collectionView.delegate = dataSource
```

**Longer version**:

For Me this was a small mistake -

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

This would call these methods

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

However it would **NOT** call

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Because this is not part of UICollectionView 's dataSource. It's part of UICollectionView's delegate.

So adding the following solved my issue.

```
collectionView.delegate = dataSource
```

Comment: Why are you setting collectionView.delegate = dataSource instead of collectionView.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem! If you make the size half the width (width/2), then it will still appear like the entire width because the padding is being added to the width/2.

Fix: Make sure to set the section insets in Storyboard to 0. Alternatively, adjust the width/2 to a size that INCLUDES the section insets.

It took me a while to fix that one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to assign **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** object to your **collectionViewLayout** since UICollectionView uses UICollectionViewLayout (not UICollectionView**Flow**Layout) by default.

> let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
>
> collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout